# Get blank screen

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I rewrite info.phtml but when I open my order view info tab it shows blank page.

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" type="Aalogics\TrainingVoucher\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this block in top of your file info.phtml :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

See the result of the error.

Do any `echo "test";` or `die('1231');` , cache clean , and see if it shows anything . 
Open the template hints and check the template you are on .

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: Updated my answer @3434

Answer (score 0):

1. change to developer mode:

> bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

2. try run compile:

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

3.Enable show error in
index.php

> ini_set('display_errors', 1);
>
> rename pub/error/local.xml.sample to pub/error/local.xml

4. Enable templates hints.

If you still can't see your error. Pls upload your code ,we can investigate :)